# mysql Join table, even with null result in relation

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql-database with 3 tables:

```
case (caseID), question_nl (case, question) and question_fr (case, question)
```

Both question_nl and question_fr are linked to case. Now I want to perform a suery to give me all cases with their representing value from _nl or _fr. The problem occurs when there is no entry in one of the two tables. I want to get a result, even if the question is null

for example: case 1 has as question_nl 'AAA' and as question_fr 'BBB'. case 2 has not yet any question set in _nl or _fr. Now I want a query that outputs the caseID and the question (null if not set), so the query should have:

```
1 - AAA - BBB
2 - null - null
```

How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT C.caseId, N.question, F.question
FROM cases C JOIN
     question_nl N 
     ON N.case = C.caseID JOIN 
     question_fr F
     ON F.case = C.caseID
```

This does not work...

Some help would be very nice!

UPDATE: and what if I have to add a WHERE-clausule on the _nl or _fr?

Comment: You're looking for a `LEFT JOIN` here, not an inner `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`s instead:

```
SELECT C.caseId, N.question, F.question
FROM cases C 
LEFT JOIN question_nl N ON N.case = C.caseID 
LEFT JOIN question_fr F ON F.case = C.caseID
```

Answer (score 0):

use a LEFT JOIN:

```
    SELECT C.caseId
         , N.question
         , F.question 
    FROM cases C 
    LEFT JOIN question_nl N
        ON N.case = C.caseID 
    LEFT JOIN question_fr F 
        ON F.case = C.caseID
```